# CSS only - how to have a scrolling ul with all li on one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a fixed width. Inside is an ul. The ul has a random amount of li children, with varying widths.

I use bootstrap.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">    
        <ul id="inner" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>         
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="parent">    
   <div class="child">        
        <ul id="inner-new" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>        
    </div> 
</div>

<style>
.parent {
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

li {
    padding: 30px;
}

#inner {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}

#inner-new {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
```

Here is a fiddle with above code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/2/

Is there a way to have the li's all in one row (like it is in the first example) but without giving the ul a fixed width? Since I don't know how many li's there will be or what width any of them will be, I can't add use fixed widths. I can also only use CSS for this.

I tried various things with float:left and different display styles, but I couldn't figure it out. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Here is a little picture, to make it clearer (hopefully!) 
http://i.imgur.com/Qz9eUD2.png

Comment: @Pete, if I give the ul a width of 100% it will insert every li in its own line: http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/9/. I want them all in the same line. How could I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/5/)

```
.parent1{
width:100%;
}
```

> then You please check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/8/)
>
> if i understand you i think you want something like this [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/11/)
>
> according to your image [final demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/13/)

Comment: My english isn't very good so I probably expressed myself wrong, I'm looking for a way to still have the green div at 200px but the ul inside as big as the sum of it's children. So I want a small green box with a very long, scrolling yellow box inside.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have no idea how to explain what I'm trying to do. Your demo is really close, however I'm trying to get all 'li' into one line - without giving my ul a fixed width.

Comment: you can draw a image and show me i will try to resolve your problem

Comment: Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/Qz9eUD2.png - I hope this clears things up. Please don't laugh at my ms paint skills.

Comment: Sadly, this still isn't what I am looking for. All li's need to be on one line - but without giving the ul a fixed width, as the amount of li's and their width is not known.

Comment: Your demo looks very promising! Could we maybe chat, so you can explain to me in detail how this works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81634/discussion-between-priya786-and-sirence).

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't find how to start a chat with you - but it's alright, I figured out how the rotate works - thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check this update link:

http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/3/

Css code:

```
.parent {
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height:400px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not what I am looking for. I realise the problem comes from my bad english and not being able to express my needs properly. Could you check the comments I added to priya786's answer to get a better idea of what I'm trying to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just ***remove*** the width (`width: 200px;`) from the class ".parent".

Comment: The thing is, I need the parent to be exactly 200px. If I remove the width it will expand to the size of it's children. I do not want that, I need the child to scroll inside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you just need Following changes with #inner class

-**Add this properties**

max-height: 150px;   //set the maximum width of particulate div above that height scroll bar will shown 
  overflow-y: auto;     // allowing the scroll after what maximum height has been set to the particular div or element.

**Remove this properties**

width : 500px; // this will set the div's width to 500 px and the parent class is having the "display : inline-block" property so this property will extended automatically to the child class 
so here may you can change one of them as per your choice..

```css
.parent {
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

li {
    padding: 30px;
}

#inner {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  /* width: 500px; */
  /* max-width: 200px; */
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 150px;
}

#inner-new {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

you can check whether you are searching about this or else.
you can set max-height with whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you want, i used to stuck in same problem.
Don't use ul and li.
check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/14/) or below code

```css
.wrapper{
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}

.wrapper span{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p class="wrapper">
       <span>Child 1</span>
       <span>Child 2</span>
       <span>Child 3</span>
       <span>Child 4</span>
       <span>Child 5</span>
       <span>Child 6</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks very great! Can you elaborate why it doesn't work with ul and li?

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit of your code, the main problem was (I think) that the bootstrap is giving the li a float:left; and a display:block, so I changed that to display: inline-block; and removed the float, and added the list-style: none to li, white-space: nowrap; and overflow-y: hidden; maybe this is what you want.

```
.parent {
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

li {
    padding: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: none !important;
}

#inner {
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

#inner-new {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```